# Juntar três funções em uma só(um só arquivo)

Tags: javascript

Tenho três funções independentes, que fazem tarefas distintas. Gostaria de juntar essas três funções em uma só, mas que façam a mesma coisa que as três, de forma independente fazem. Como eu posso conseguir isso?
OBS: As três funções estão funcionando, sem nenhum erro. Só preciso mesmo juntá-las em uma só. A última função recebe um argumento, `event`, e executa quando uma linha na tabela é alterada. As duas primeiras funções executam a cada minuto(trigger do googledocs)

Função 1: Esconde linhas de uma tabela googledocs

```
function escondeLinhas() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AlertaCompleto"); //Altere o nome da aba
var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
var arr=sheet.getRange(1,11,lastRow,1).getValues(); //Substitua o 3 pelo nº da coluna onde se encontra a string a ser pesquisada
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i][0]=="Concluido no Prazo" || arr[i][0]=="Concluido Fora do Prazo") {
         sheet.hideRows(i+1);  //ESCONDE A LINHA
      }
    }
}
```

Função 2: Gera uma URL de um endereço de células no googledocs

```
    function geraURL() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('AlertaCompleto');
     //  var data = new Date();
    //   data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00","dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' '"); verificar possibilidade de inserir data de atualização de informações automaticamente

      for (var i=2; i<1000;i++) {
        if (spreadsheet.getRange('C'+i).getValue()!= "") {//Se coluna C contiver algum valor, gerar URL na coluna L
            spreadsheet.getRange('L'+i).activate();
            spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11RyO150lEMkDB/edit#gid=1131&range='+i+':'+i);
            //spreadsheet.getRange("I"+i).setValue(data); //Erro. Atualiza ate a linha 9

            spreadsheet.getRange('A'+i+':'+'K'+i).activate(); //aplica borda
            spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
            .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);

      }
    }
}
```

Função 3: Atualiza a data em uma célula do googledocs

```
function onEdit(event) {
 var ActiveSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var capture = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
   if(capture.getColumn() == 9 || capture.getColumn() == 10 && ActiveSheet.getName() == "AlertaCompleto" ){
     var add = capture.offset(0,4);
       var data = new Date();
       data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00","dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' '");
       add.setValue(data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não recomendo fazer isso. Não agregue suas funções em uma só. Deixa-as diluídas como estão, afinal, as funções tem a função (*pun intended!*) de compartimentar o código em tarefas mais simples para tornar fáceis as alterações e manutenção do código.

Também não recomendo criar variáveis globais para os códigos repetitivos, em vez disso, "embale" (***wrap***) seu código. Estude algumas [**arquiteturas JS**](https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/arquitetura-de-software-em-javascript-ports-interfaces-e-interactors-d6e826b9d3aa) e escolha a que melhor se adequa ao seu problema.

No caso simples apresentado aqui, recomendaria um ***singleton***, que é genericamente o mais usado. Isso mostra sua simplicidade e efetividade em conter o [***hoisting***](https://walde.co/2016/02/15/javascript-hoisting-o-que-e/) e criar um código organizado e fácil de manter, o que é, sem dúvida, uma coisa excelente.

Você cria um objeto:

```
var googSpreadSheet = (function() {

    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AlertaCompleto");

    return {
        escondeLinhas: function() {
            var lastRow = this.sheet.getLastRow();
            var arr = this.sheet.getRange(1, 11, lastRow, 1).getValues(); //Substitua o 3 pelo nº da coluna onde se encontra a string a ser pesquisada
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i][0] == "Concluido no Prazo" || arr[i][0] == "Concluido Fora do Prazo") {
                    this.sheet.hideRows(i + 1); //ESCONDE A LINHA
                }
            }
        },

        geraURL: function() {
            for (var i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
                if (spreadsheet.getRange('C' + i).getValue() != "") { //Se coluna C contiver algum valor, gerar URL na coluna L
                    spreadsheet.getRange('L' + i).activate();
                    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11RyO150lEMkDB/edit#gid=1131&range=' + i + ':' + i);
                    spreadsheet.getRange('A' + i + ':' + 'K' + i).activate(); //aplica borda
                    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
                        .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM);

                }
            }
        },

        onEdit: function(event) {
            var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
            var capture = ActiveSheet.getActiveCell();
            if (capture.getColumn() == 9 || capture.getColumn() == 10 && ActiveSheet.getName() == "AlertaCompleto") {
                var add = capture.offset(0, 4);
                var data = new Date();
                data = Utilities.formatDate(data, "GMT-03:00", "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' '");
                add.setValue(data);
            }
        }
    };
}());
```

Claro, nesse exemplo, que não deve ser usado em produção, você tem um exemplo bem básico, com todos os métodos sendo públicos.

Você pode acessar os métodos assim:

```
// Supondo que você clique num botão com ID "esconde-linhas"
// para executar o método googSpreadSheet.escondeLinhas(), sem parâmetros

var buttonEscondeLinhas = document.getElementById("esconde-linhas");

buttonEscondeLinhas.addEventListener("click", googSpreadSheet.escondeLinhas());
```

Dê uma olhada em JavaScript Design Patterns.

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de editar e remover o trecho final, pois embora seja uma discussão relevante (como o site funciona e como deveria funcionar, etc) não tem relação com a pergunta. Fique à vontade para abrir um tópico no [meta] sobre isso, caso deseje, pois lá é o lugar para discutir este tipo de coisa :)